# SQL WHERE clause using AND/OR operators

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have the DB below and when I try to run an SQL command it doesn't do quite what it should do (the code below should have a `cursorSize` of 1 but it shows 0).

The code I run is:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String countQuery = "SELECT  songid FROM TABLE_TRACKS WHERE (tagid = 7 OR tagid = 10) AND tagid = 9";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
int cursorSize = cursor.getCount();
```

Its something to do with the where clause, because when I change the brackets and make it

```
WHERE (tagid=9 AND tagid = 7) OR tagid=10
```

It works because `int cursorSize` is 2.
Is there something silly I am missing out or something I don't know about SQL WHERE clause or AND/OR operators?

Would really appreciate if someone could explain this for me *and* how to get the results that I want. (Below I want to return one row with `songid` equal to `3`.)

[image]

Comment: If you only have one value in the `tagid` column how can any row have _two_ `tagid`s? Because `(tagid = 7 OR tagid = 10) AND tagid = 9` demands that the `tagid` equals `9` **and** another number...

Comment: If you just need two combinations then joining the table with itself works: `SELECT DISTINCT songid FROM table_trac AS A LEFT JOIN table_trac AS B USING (songid) WHERE (A.tagid=7 OR A.tagid=10) AND B.tagid=10`. There is an A and B version of the tagid so you can select rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ther is nothing wrong with the result. It should give you zero because:

- There is no way that you have a row where the tagid = 7 and 9 at the same time.
- There is no way that you have a row where the tagid = 10 and 9 at the same time.

You need to check your app logic and what are you trying to accomplish here.

**Edit:**

`So think of songIDs as songs and tagIDs as Tags (guitar, piano, romantic and so on) so if I want to find the songs which has (piano AND guitar) OR romantic tag how is it possible ? do I have to change my db (table) or can I reformulate my sql ?`

If this is the context of your app, and you expect some input combinations from the users, I suggest you change your db scheme. try to add Boolean columns for each tag. This will be easier in case you are expecting such combinations and it will not differ that much in terms of space.

Comment: These are all excellent answers, but what is a query that gives Achilles the results that he wants?

Comment: @Sam I don't know what he wants but his code is working fine.

Comment: Achilles expects a list of `songid`s that have the one row with `tagid = 9` and another row where the `tagid = 7` or `tagid = 10`. In the example above, he wants a query that selects one row with `songid = 3`.

Comment: I think your solution makes more sense, but what about the solution @Makoto suggested ? using UNION/JOIN. Do you reckon it will be handy ?

Comment: @Achilles It might be doable. However, giving that your query depends on the user input, I think it will be a headache!

Answer (score 1):

It is working as expected.

First executes `tagid = 7 OR tagid = 10`

So results will be

```
7  2
7  3
10 4
```

Then `AND tagid = 9`

now checks for `tagid 9` in above results

There is nothing available. So, cursor size is `ZERO`

Comment: These are all excellent answers, but what is a query that gives Achilles the results that he wants?

Comment: @Sam: I think based on his question, what he is expecting is, why first query is not working, which is explained in answer. Do you see anything else there?

Comment: Hidden in the question: "Is there something silly I am missing out or something I don't know about SQL WHERE clause or AND/OR operators(?)" I believe he would like a query that returns one row with `songid = 3` from his example above. (I'm relatively il-SQLiterate, otherwise I'd put an answer myself...)

Comment: Yes it should return songid = 3 because it has ONE OF (7 OR 10) and it has the 9 which should meet the condition {(7 OR 10) AND 9}

Comment: @Achilles: Is it possible to change AND songID = 3?

Comment: the issue is this whole WHERE clause is arbitrary provided by the user and it will often change, In the above condition i provided, songid 3 meets the condition as it has tagid 9 and also meets the OR condition.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the CursorSize is 0 is because your query contains a logical error.
Your query says: `(tagid = 7 OR tagid = 10) AND tagid = 9`.

Think of this query as two different conditional statements joined by an AND operator which means that if your `tagid` is 7 AND `tagid = 9` then your `cursorSize` is updated. How can your `tagid` be both 7 and 9? I think what you are need to do is use 7 OR 9 if you want to use the `songid` from `tagid 7` and `tagid 9`.

The reason why `(tagid=9 AND tagid = 7) OR tagid=10` gives you a non-zero `cursorSize` is because now, you are using an OR operator as I suggested above so at least in the case where `tagid == 10` you get back a database entry.

Comment: These are all excellent answers, but what is a query that gives Achilles the results that he wants? Also check out [answer] for hints on formatting your answers.

Comment: So think of songIDs as songs and tagIDs as Tags (guitar, piano, romantic and so on) so if I want to find the songs which has piano AND guitar tag OR romantic how is it possible ? do I have to change my db (table) or can I reformulate my sql ?

Answer (score 1):

This boolean statement:

```
(tagid = 7 OR tagid = 10) AND tagid = 9
```

implies that `tagid` must be both 7 (or 10) AND 9 at the same time.  That's not going to work.

The reason that this boolean statement:

```
(tagid=9 AND tagid = 7) OR tagid=10
```

works is because there are two rows with the value 10 in `tagid`.

Comment: These are all excellent answers, but what is a query that gives Achilles the results that he wants?

Comment: @Sam:  He hasn't made clear *what* he wants from the query.  He's only stated what's wrong.  If he wanted one of the rows, then he'd only need to keep one of the equality statements, or if he wanted a range of rows, he could switch it to an inequality.

Comment: Achilles expects a list of `songid`s that have the one row with `tagid = 9` and another row where the `tagid = 7` or `tagid = 10`. In the example above, he wants a query that selects one row with `songid = 3`.

Comment: So think of songIDs as songs and tagIDs as Tags (guitar, piano, romantic and so on) so if I want to find the songs which has (piano AND guitar) OR romantic tag how is it possible ? do I have to change my db (table) or can I reformulate my sql ?

Comment: Yes its pretty much what @Sam wrote.

Comment: @Achilles:  You have two choices - you can use `UNION`/`JOIN` on that table with the different parameters, or you can reform your SQL table to accommodate different columns.  `UNION`/`JOIN` would be the better route; multiple columns would be the easier route.

Comment: the where clause will be arbitrary provided by users so it will often be different combination of AND/OR/NOT expressions. will it still work with ur provided solution ?

Comment: @Achilles if that is the case, I suggest you change your db scheme. try to add Boolean columns for each tag. This will be easier in case you are expecting such combinations.

Comment: @iturki That was what I initially thought, but if list of available unique tagsids are larger, it would mean a column for each unique tagid right ?

Comment: @Achilles:  At this point, you would be best served creating a new question around how to improve your SQL schema.  This one only covers what's wrong with your query.

Comment: @Achilles but it will still a boolean value. And it will make more sense because you have one row for each song.